# Update field solr with php client

Tags: solr

how can I update a stored field with solr and the php client ?

Do I have to make a query, parse the response, get the id and add the document again ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Which PHP client? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi again I m using version 2.3.0...